# How to share my redmine account to other members added to my project

Tags: redmine

I have registered my Redmine in 127.0.0.1/redmine and added few members in my account with username and password. But when those users are logging in their system, then they not able to log in and view my projects. How can they access my project?

Expected: -When I add a user with their email-id, then they should be able to login with the credentials and should be able to see my all activity

Answer (score 0):

(1)
127.0.0.1 is a localhost address, its purpose is to serve requests only within your *system*. To allow other users to log in to your Redmine instance you should bind it to routable IP address of your *host*, basically by adding `-b 0.0.0.0` to `rails server` command. Assuming there are no firewalls in your environment, users will connect to Redmine using your *host* name or routable IP address on port 3000 by default.

(2)
To be able to view some Redmine project, user should be a member of this project. Project's members and their roles are configured through [Project Settings](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineProjectSettings)